# My page is not redirect properly

Tags: php

I have one problem to redirect my page with email id.My page is redirect properly but not showing email id at the time of redirect.

```
not working code
$email2='shakti@gmail.com';


$var = 'location:';
$var .= 'https://www.ymlp.com/api/Contacts.Add?Key=5ESTZPSGT8AFJV5Y2Y4Q&Username=38bf&Email=$email2&GroupID=5';
header ($var);
It's showing variable name.

working code:
$var = 'location:';
$var .= 'https://www.ymlp.com/api/Contacts.Add?Key=5ESTZPSGT8AFJV5Y2Y4Q&Username=38bf&Email=shakti@gmail.com&GroupID=5';
header ($var);
```

It's not showing variable name.

```
Thanks for your great help
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, variables in php are not parsed inside single quotes.
Close the string and append the variable inside using "." to concatenate.
This way: 'first part of a string '.$variable.' second part of a string';
So what you need is:

```
$var .= 'https://www.ymlp.com/api/Contacts.Add?Key=5ESTZPSGT8AFJV5Y2Y4Q&Username=38bf&Email='.$email2.'&GroupID=5';
```

Another solution would be to use double quotes instead -> "Text with $variable inside".

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$var .= 'https://www.ymlp.com/api/Contacts.Add?Key=5ESTZPSGT8AFJV5Y2Y4Q&Username=38bf&Email='.$email2.'&GroupID=5';
```

Or you could use

```
$var .= "https://www.ymlp.com/api/Contacts.Add?Key=5ESTZPSGT8AFJV5Y2Y4Q&Username=38bf&Email=$email2&GroupID=5";
```

Note the double quotes.

Edit: Single quotes string do not evaluate variables so if you are using single quotes do proper concatenation otherwise use double quotes for strings wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it out and works well with single quotes.

```
$email2='shakti@gmail.com';


$var = 'location:';
$var .= 'https://www.ymlp.com/api/Contacts.Add?Key=5ESTZPSGT8AFJV5Y2Y4Q&Username=38bf&Email='.$email2.'&GroupID=5';
header ($var);
```

Here is the result:

```
<Result>
<Code>0</Code>
<Output>shakti@gmail.com has been added</Output>
</Result>
```

and is showing the email on the url as this:

```
https://www.ymlp.com/api/Contacts.Add?Key=5ESTZPSGT8AFJV5Y2Y4Q&Username=38bf&Email=shakti@gmail.com&GroupID=5
```